# Linear Mixed Models with GARCH Errors

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, garch

Currently, I'm trying to analyze the factors affecting rice prices in certain localities over five years. I have monthly data on rice prices of 60 localities for 2015 to 2020.

I would like to investigate this through mixed models but with GARCH errors --- since there seems to be volatility clustering in the rice prices. That is for the $i^{th}$ locality, following Pinheiro & Bates (2006),

$$\bf{y_{i}} = \bf{X_{i}}\beta + \bf{Z_i}b_i + \epsilon_{i}$$
$$b_i \sim N(0, \Sigma), \epsilon_i \sim N(0,  \Delta)$$
I would want to model $\Delta$ through a GARCH(1,1) process.

I saw that the nlme package could handle ARMA errors through corARMA. I initially tried constructing my own corStruct class in nlme but could not figure out where to start in modifying the corMatrix and coef functions for GARCH processes.

I don't have much experience with temporal correlations in mixed models and I am trying to catch up on the literature.

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could give pointers on where to start with corStruct classes for GARCH in nlme or in implementing mixed models with GARCH errors in another package like lme4, thank you! :)

EDIT:
Upon further reading of Pinheiro & Bates (2006), I read that $\Delta_i$ = $V_iC_iV_i$ where $V_i$ describes the variance and $C_i$ describes the correlation of within-group errors $\epsilon_i$. As such, should I instead focus on the modifying the varFunc classes in nlme, instead of the corStruct classes?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?